# Cloud Formation: Environment failed to launch as it entered Terminated state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am building an elastic beanstalk environment. I get the above error when I run the template. I have added the IAM roles giving full EC2 access to cloud formation

```
 Resources:
  TestApp:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application'
    Properties: {}
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 53bb2af6-3a68-487a-8048-34f111147171

  EBE1RNK0:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref TestApp
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Node Sample Application
      EnvironmentName: NodejsEnvironment
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.0.1 running Node.js 12
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: InstanceType
          Value: t1.micro
```

[image]

Comment: If you go to EB console, click on failed deployment, you should be able to see some more useful error message than this.

Comment: As a side note. `t2.micro` is newer then `t1.micro` and it is also in the free tier.

Comment: The issue i am having is that it creates the SampleApplication but When it moves to SampleEnvironment it gives the "Environment Failed to Launch as it entered Terminated Sate". It then says Following Resources failed to create: [Sample Environment]. Rollback requested by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the screen shot, it failed just after trying to access S3 - theres your suspect. [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles-instance.html) say beanstalk will require access to S3, Xray and CloudWatch Logs and provide below example policy. Do your roles include these permissions?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "BucketAccess",
      "Action": [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "XRayAccess",
      "Action": [
        "xray:PutTraceSegments",
        "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "CloudWatchLogsAccess",
      "Action": [
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
        "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, Yes I have had the necessary permissions. i have solved the error. it was due to me not adding the instance profile Role. it allows you to pass role information to an EC2 instance when the instance starts.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I have missed out on adding the instance profile, as that would enable me to pass information to an EC2 when the instance starts running.

This should be below your options settings. Show below.

```
OptionSettings:
    - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
      OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
      Value: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
```